# Is there any way to return a custom error code in case of a failure on LoadLibrary() in Windows or dlopen() in Linux? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, linux, windows, dlopen, loadlibrary

Currently I am trying to create a system of an executable (.exe/.out), which performs delayed importing of a dynamic library (.dll/.so), lying nearby, using LoadLibrary()/dlopen() and GetProcAddress()/dlsym().

Suppose, in Windows (primary objective at this point) I write the following code for the executable to load the dynamic library (a pretty artificial example, but would go I guess):

```
...
HMODULE hModule = LoadLibraryA("MyDll.dll");
if (hModule == nullptr)
{
    std::cout << "Last error code = " << GetLastError();
    return;
}
...
```

And the following code for the dynamic library:

```
BOOL DllMain(...)
{
    ...
    if (!someFileExists)
    {
        SetLastError(myCustomErrorCode);
        return FALSE;
    }
    ...
}
```

Of course, the myCustomErrorCode cannot be 'translated' to the executable in such way. The same basically applies to Linux (exactly the same functionality is to be distributed across several platforms, but refering to the **attribute**((constructor))-marked routine). What are possible variants to inform the executable that the dynamic library could not be loaded? I was thinking about SEH and events for Windows, but these do not seem to be suitable. Any platform-specific or cross-platform (I do not think there is one, but may be...?) solution for Windows and/or Linux would go!

Comment: There is no option for a DllMain to directly report custom errors to the loading code. Write the error info to a log file, and then have the loader/user read it.

Comment: Related - on Windows, you'll want to be very conservative about what you're doing in `DllMain`() - see [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).

Comment: You should use an own `init` function in your dll. (Like JNI_OnLoad in Java Native Interface)